# Passing a Parameter between two choices to a class

Tags: c++, class, parameters

How can I pass an Object of type `Push` **or** `Pull` into an Object of type `Object Pool`?

I am simulating an `Object Pool` in C++. I've made a function called `Request()` which can receive a Parameter of either `Pull` or `Push`.

Is it possible? And if so, how?

***Thank you in advance***.

---

Here is the code example:

```
template <class T>
class ObjectPool {
    public:
        T Request(T* Object) {
            // This is the part that seems unclear to me.
            // Basically, in Pseudocode it looks like:
            // if Object.type == Pull, then do:
            //     Steps to Generate an Object.
            // else if Object.type == Push:
            //     Steps to store an Object.
        }

        ObjectPool() {
        }

        ~ObjectPool() {
        }
}
```

Comment: you can overload the request function, but it is hard to be more precise without the real code

Comment: Overloading perhaps? It's kind of unclear exactly what you're doing and what you want to accomplish. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend you read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and *all* of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might get voted down.

Comment: @acraig5075 I gave this answer below, I also think it's the best idea. einpoklum solution with templates is a bit tricky for neophytes.

Comment: I have added a code example. Both of the answers given by @user30701 and einoklum helped me.

Comment: @EdwinPratt: But note that I had to essentially write 2 answers, with only one being properly relevant to your specific case. That's a lesson in why it's important to include example code.

Comment: @einpoklum Thank you. From now on, I will add code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the Pool class is templated on the request parameter:**

You have two options:

1. Just make your pseudocode into code:

   ```
   T Request (T* Object) {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<T,Push> or std::is_same_v<T,Pull>,
            "Unsupported pool element type");
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,Pull>) {
            /* do stuff for Pulls */
        }
        else { // i.e. std::is_same_v<T,Push> {
            /* do stuff for Pushes */
        }
   };
   ```
2. Not provide a general implementation, but rather two specializations, for `Pull` and for `Push` respectively.

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class Pool{
       /* ... */
       T Request (T* Object);
       /* ... */
   };

   template<> Pool<Pull>::Request(Pull* pull) { /* etc. */ }
   template<> Pool<Push>::Request(Push* push) { /* etc. */ }
   ```

---

**If the Pool class is not templated on the request parameter:**

You need to be more specific in your question, but:

1. (As @Tyker and @SomeProgrammerDude suggest) you can overload the request method:

   ```
   class Pool {
       /* ... */
       SomeType request(const Push& p);
       SomeType request(const Pull& p);
   };
   ```
2. You can template the request method over the request type:

   ```
   class Pool {
       /* ... */
       template <typename T>
       SomeType request(const T& request_param);
   };
   ```
3. You could use a [variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), where values can have either one type or another type - like a (disjoint) union of the two types:

   ```
   class Pool {
       /* ... */
       using request_param_type = std::variant<Push, Pull>;
       template <typename T>
       SomeType request(request_param_type request_param);
   };
   ```

   and then you can have code which explicitly decides (at run-time) what to do for what class. It will not be templated code, i.e. you can expose the header without the implementation.

   Now the code above is a bit problematic, since the way I've written it, you're making a copy of the `Push` or `Pull` object and you might not want to do that. In that case try:

   ```
   template<class...Ts>
   using variant_of_const_refs = std::variant<std::reference_wrapper<const Ts>...>;

   class Pool {
       /* ... */
       using request_param_type = variant_of_const_refs<Push, Pull>;
       template <typename T>
       SomeType request(request_param_type request_param);
   }
   ```

Comment: I'd like to learn more about Generics. If you can, may you please comment a link for Generics?

Comment: @EdwinPratt: Well, there's a series of 4 videos on YouTube you could take a look at, starting with [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvUMMljFzfI), but you should really take one of the [textbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282). If you want to go in deep, there's a specific textbook on the subject: [C++ Generics: The Complete Guide](http://tmplbook.com/) (make sure you read the second, not the first, edition.)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by inheritance, both your Pull and Push object inherit from a parent class.

```
class Push: public BaseClass { /* ... */ };
class Pull: public BaseClass { /* ... */ };

void Request(BaseClass* action) { /* ... */ }
```

So you can give ether a Pull or a Push Object to your Request function.

Comment: But this would mean that OP must have a Pool of BaseClass, which may contain both Push'es and Pull's.

Comment: Not as I intend it, push and pull are instruction for the pool, those objects may contains information about the instruction (how many object to push/pull, callbacks, etc...). The pool instanciate its own pool objects.